# How to select only columns with sequence names to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, sequence, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe containing columns of [ProDT, ID,..., D1, D2, D3...D7...]. I want to extract a list of column names of D1~D15.

I applied the code:

```
df_D = [col for col in df.columns if 'D' in col]
```

However, all columns that contain the character 'D' are selected. 
The number D* columns may change, so using range(1,7) may not be a good solution.

Many thanks.

Comment: In my opinion solution to your problem is data frame.ix indexing. As described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select all columns matching the following pattern:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^D\d+')
```

**Details**

- `^D\d+`

  - `^` asserts position at start of a line
  - `D` matches the character D literally (case sensitive)
  - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

Comment: Thanks so much. I used: list=df.filter(regex=r'^D\d+').columns.tolist(), sorted.

Comment: Could you explain how the 'r'^D\d+' works? Many thanks

Comment: Added some details @SherenaHendricks for detailed info you can check https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

The good old list comprehension with `startswith`:

```
df[[i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('D')]]
```

Or:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('D')]  #thanks @WeNYoBen
```

Comment: df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('D')] :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen yes, `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('D')] ` may be for this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can either call each column :

```
df[['D1', 'D2', ..., 'D15']]
```

or use a filter:

```
df.filter(like='D')
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`df = df[['D'+str(i) for i in range(1, 16)]]`